# Customize padding between Navigation View menu items

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, androiddesignsupport, android-navigationview

Is it possible to customize spacing between menu items in android design support library `NavigationView` ?

My requirement is to create a submenu in `NavigationView` in which menu items have less spacing between them then parent menu.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried app:itemTextAppearance? for example use like that

```
app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"
```

After you should create edit your style.xml and declare your style:

```
<style name="NavDrawerTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">something</item>
</style>
```